# Azure Classic Storage - Do I need to worry about TLS Critical Change?

Tags: azure, ssl-certificate, azure-storage

We received an email from MS saying that there is a critical TLS change for Azure Storage but we are still on classic storage.  Do I need to worry about this change? I'm asking because I'm having a hard time finding where to even check for this.

Here is the email:

> Azure Storage TLS: Critical changes are almost here! (…and why you
> should care) By ozge Ozge Gun Published Sep 12 2021 10:25 PM  29K
> Views Skip to footer content This blog contains important information
> about TLS certificate changes for Azure Storage endpoints that may
> impact client connectivity.
>
> In 2020 most Azure services were updated to use TLS certificates from
> Certificate Authorities (CAs) that chain up to the DigiCert Global G2
> root. However,  Azure Storage, remained on TLS certificates issued by
> the Baltimore CyberTrust Root. The time has now come for Azure Storage
> to switch from the Baltimore CyberTrust CA Root to the DigiCert Global
> G2 CA Root*. The migration will start in July 2022, and finish by end
> of October 2022.
>
> We expect that most Azure Storage customers will not be impacted;
> however, your application may be impacted if you explicitly specify a
> list of acceptable CAs (a practice known as “certificate pinning”). In
> scope Azure Storage services include Blob, File, Table, Queue, Static
> Website, ADLS Gen2. This change is limited to public Azure cloud and
> US Government cloud. There are no changes in other sovereign clouds
> like Azure China.
>
> This change is being made because the current "Baltimore CyberTrust
> Root" will expire in May 2025.
>
> If any client application has pinned to the root CA Baltimore
> CyberTrust Root or current intermediate CAs listed in the table below,
> immediate action is required to prevent disruption to connectivity to
> Azure Storage.
>
> - Other Azure service TLS certificates may be issued by a different PKI.
>
> Action Required
>
> If your client application has pinned to the Baltimore CyberTrust Root
> CA, in addition to Baltimore, add the DigiCert Global Root G2 to your
> trusted root store before February 2022.  If your client application
> has pinned to the intermediate CAs, in addition to Microsoft RSA TLS
> CAs, add the Microsoft Azure TLS Issuing CAs to your trusted root
> store before February 2022.  Keep using the current root or
> intermediate CAs in your applications or devices until the transition
> period is completed (necessary to prevent connection interruption).
> Make sure SHA384 for Server certificate processing is enabled on the
> device.   How to check
>
> 1. If your client application has pinned to
>
> Root CA: Baltimore CyberTrust Root CA or,   Intermediate CA:
> Microsoft RSA TLS CA 01  Intermediate CA:  Microsoft RSA TLS CA 02
> detailed in the table below, then search your source code for the
> thumbprint, Common Name, and other cert properties of any of the root
> CA or intermediate CAs. If there is a match, then your application
> will be impacted, immediate action is required:
>
> To continue without disruption due to this change, Microsoft
> recommends that client applications or devices trust the root CA –
> DigiCert Global Root G2:  DigiCert Global Root G2  (Thumbprint:
> df3c24f9bfd666761b268073fe06d1cc8d4f82a4)
>
> Intermediate certificates are expected to change more frequently than
> root CA. Customers who use certificate pinning are recommended to not
> taking dependencies on them and instead pin to the root certificate as
> it rolls less frequently.   If you are currently pinning to the
> intermediate CAs and have a requirement to continue pinning to
> intermediate CAs, to prevent disruption due to this change, you should
> update the source code to add the intermediate Microsoft Azure TLS
> Issuing CAs listed in the table below to the trusted store.
>
> 2. To prevent future disruption, you should also add the following roots to the trusted store. This will save you from the allowlist
>    effort in near future if you add the recommended root CAs now:
>
> DigiCert Global Root G3  (Thumbprint:
> 7e04de896a3e666d00e687d33ffad93be83d349e)  Microsoft RSA Root
> Certificate Authority 2017  (Thumbprint:
> 73a5e64a3bff8316ff0edccc618a906e4eae4d74)  Microsoft ECC Root
> Certificate Authority 2017  (Thumbprint:
> 999a64c37ff47d9fab95f14769891460eec4c3c5)
>
> Note: If you have a requirement to pin to intermediate CAs, to prevent
> future disruption, you should also add the intermediate Microsoft
> Azure ECC TLS CAs listed in the table below to the trusted store.
>
> 3. If you have completed the step 1 and need to validate your changes, we can provide a test environment on demand for your convenience to
>    verify prior to July 2022. To request a test storage account, please
>    open a support request with the options below and a member from our
>    engineering team will get back to you.
>
> For Issue type, select Technical. For Subscription, select your
> subscription.  For Service, select My Services, then select Blob
> Storage. For Resource, select your resource.  For Summary, enter
> #storagecertificatetest.  For Problem type, select Connectivity.  For Problem subtype, select Dropped or terminated connections.

Comment: that is the relevant sentence for you. You need to know yourself if your answer to that is yes or no: "We expect that most Azure Storage customers will not be impacted; however, your application may be impacted if you explicitly specify a list of acceptable CAs (a practice known as “certificate pinning”)."

Comment: @silent Agreed.  It is a setup I inherited and I'm trying to find out how to see if we have any certs pinned but I have to rely on web searches for that and ... long story but I was hoping that maybe classic storage wasn't affected and I wouldn't even have to worry about it but I'll keep doing research.